# get count rows per minute in two tables have different primary keys

Tags: sql

I have time series data in the first table like:

| opt | opt_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2023-04-10 12:20:00 |
| 2 | 2023-04-10 12:20:03 |
| 3 | 2023-04-10 12:21:03 |
| 4 | 2023-04-10 12:22:03 |
| 5 | 2023-04-10 13:05:00 |
| 6 | 2023-04-10 13:05:10 |

and in the second table:

| opt | opt_date |
| --- | --- |
| 7 | 2023-04-10 12:21:00 |
| 9 | 2023-04-10 13:05:00 |

I can get the count of records per minute in each table, by running the following query:

I want to get count of rows in each minute then get the average of records in minute
My query is:

```
  select datepart(hh,opt_date), 
         datepart(mi,opt_date), 
         count(*) 
    from mytable
group by datepart(hh,opt_date), 
         datepart(mi,opt_date) 
order by datepart(hh,opt_date), 
         datepart(mi,opt_date)
```

NOW, I want to get the sume of recored per minute from the two tables, the expected result is:

| opt_date | count(*) |
| --- | --- |
| 2023-04-10 12:20:00 | 2 |
| 2023-04-10 12:21:03 | 2 |
| 2023-04-10 12:22:03 | 1 |
| 2023-04-10 13:05:00 | 4 |

kindly note that it is possible to have 0 record in table2 in a specific minute (such as in 12:20 or in 12:22)

Regards

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (datepart() is a product specific function.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have several dates in the dable (say, `11 Apr 2023`, not only `10 Apr 2023`) you, probably, want to preserve date part, and group by it as well,
i.e. instead of *extracting* hours and minutes *trim* seconds and their fractions.

I suggest `union` (`union all` to be exact) all records to be grouped (let it be `cte`) and then, having raw data, group and order them:

```
with cte as (
  select SmallDateTimeFromParts(
           datepart(year, opt_date),
           datepart(month, opt_date),
           datepart(day, opt_date),
           datepart(hour, opt_date),
           datepart(minute,opt_date)) dt 
    from myTable1

   union all

  select SmallDateTimeFromParts(
           datepart(year, opt_date),
           datepart(month, opt_date),
           datepart(day, opt_date),
           datepart(hour, opt_date),
           datepart(minute,opt_date))
    from myTable2
)

  select dt as opt_date,
         count(*) 
    from cte
group by dt
order by dt
```

Comment: Thanks for replying, I used your query but I replaced the first 3 rows related to datepart(year, month and day)  by the "convert(date,opt_date,101)"  it worked well

Answer (score 0):

i did not tested as You did not provided tables names etc but something like this should work

```sql
WITH CTE  (opt, opt_date)
AS
(
    select opt, opt_date) from table1
    union all
    select opt, opt_date) from table2
)
select datepart(hh,opt_date), 
         datepart(mi,opt_date), 
         count(*) 
    from CTE  
group by datepart(hh,opt_date), 
         datepart(mi,opt_date) 
order by datepart(hh,opt_date), 
         datepart(mi,opt_date)
```